# how to access site master navigation menues' value to any aspx page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a website using default "Site.master" master page. I want to access the value of menu item available at navigation menu in Site.master. For example "Home" and "About" navigation menu item's value. I'm new & need some help.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast. In your page based on a master page, do this:

```
var pro = (this.Master as YourMasterPageClassName).SomeInternalToMasterProperty;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Menu mn = (Menu)Master.FindControl("id_of_menu_control");
            foreach (MenuItem item in mn.Items)
            {
                string navigate = item.NavigateUrl;
/// Other stuffs you want to do
            }
```

Comment: my problem is that I have 4 items on navigation menu- Home, About, ITEM1 and ITEM2. navigationUrl for Home is Home.aspx, for About is about.aspx but I used same aspx page (mypage.aspx with a label;label1)  for both ITEM1 and ITEM2. I want to label1.text according to what menu I clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I have done it...

```
 Control allUsers = this.Page.Master.FindControl("login").FindControl("loginview").FindControl("ulmenu").FindControl("allUsers");
```

The above is use on my page load if an "Admin" logs in. Then this is what is in my site.master...

```
<section runat="server" id="login">
                        <asp:LoginView id="loginview" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                            <LoggedInTemplate>
                                <p id="paragraph">
                                    Welcome,
                                    <asp:LoginName ID="loginName" runat="server" CssClass="username" />
                                    </a>!
                                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" />
                                    <ul runat="server" id="ulmenu" class="menu">
                                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Dashboard.aspx">Dashboard</a></li>
                                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/DeliveredDeals.aspx">Delivered Deals</a></li>
                                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/DealTracking.aspx">Deal Tracking</a></li>
                                        <li><a runat="server" id="allUsers" href="~/Account/Garage.aspx" visible="false">Garage</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </p>
                            </LoggedInTemplate>
                        </asp:LoginView>
                    </section>
```

If you check my last li, you want to give it an ID so you are able to find it. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as simple as follows:

```
switch (e.Item.Value)
        {
             case "1":                        
               //code
                return;
            case "2":
               //code
                return;
            case "3":
                //code            
                return;
```